# jquery-ui-map add marker on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Currently i'm working with [jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) plugin. And i've faced one problem. Is it possible by **means of this plugin add an event listener that will add a marker on a map where user clicked on it**. After discovering an [Api of this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_api) i tried this code:

```
$('#map_canvas')
    .gmap()
    .addEventListener('click',function(event, test){
        //console.log(event);
    });
```

Where `#map_canvas` is a div element containing my map.
This code really adds an event listener but the variable event don't have a `.latLng` property. How can i manage to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google-Fu helped me. This is the [example](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-geocoding.html).

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(event, map) { 
    $(map).click( function(event) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
            'position': event.latLng, 
            'draggable': true, 
            'bounds': false
        }, function(map, marker) {
            //do whatever you need with the maker utilizing this variable
            marker.__gm_id
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(ev, map) {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'bounds': true}).click(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': 'Hello World!'}, this);
    });
})
```

for more reference [check this link](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-basic-example.html)

Comment: You simply added a marker. But i need an event listener that will place a marker where user clicked on the map.